# Converting Swift iOS animation images using imagenamed to imagewithcontentsoffile

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

Similar to: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822520/converting-imagenamed-to-imagewithcontentsoffile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21822520/converting-imagenamed-to-imagewithcontentsoffile/)

I am trying to convert my simple animation from using imagenamed to imagewithcontentsoffile

Right now, I have an array of images:

```
var myAnimation = [
UIImage(named:"00.png")!,
UIImage(named:"01.png")!,
UIImage(named:"02.png")!,
UIImage(named:"03.png")!,
]

imageView.animationImages = myAnimation
imageView.animationDuration = 1
imageView.startAnimating()
```

I'm having memory problems. So I thought I would start by not caching the image files. I know how to convert imagewithcontentsoffiles with individual files, but not in the scenario above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function.

```
func getUncachedImage (named name : String) -> UIImage?
{
    if let imgPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(name, ofType: nil)
    {
        return UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath)
    }
    return nil
}
```

You can create the image array like this

```
var myAnimation = [
    getUncachedImage(named: "00.png")!,
    getUncachedImage(named: "01.png")!,
    getUncachedImage(named: "02.png")!,
    getUncachedImage(named: "03.png")!
]
```

Comment: Many thanks! That worked perfectly and now is freeing up a ton of memory.